# AOSP project attach process

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-source

I have import aosp project to android studio. I can watch code with Android Studio.Now I would like to attach an android process to debug, but when I click the button "attach debug to android process",there is no process showing. Even I set the "show all process" checkbox, there is no process anymore. 
Any help will be appreciated

I would like to debug java code as ViewRootImpl, I am using mac

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the emulator (or device) to which processes you try to attach is built without debugging support. Try to use `eng` build target, e.g., run the following commands when you build your AOSP:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm-eng
make -j8
```

After building and running the emulator in this way you should be able to see all the processes running in the emulator.